# PHP- Simple query logging class is not returning size of array

Tags: php

I am using a simple class to log my sql queries and return the total amount of queries and time taken to execute.

```
class QueryLogger {

    public $queries = array();

    public function query($sql) {

        global $db;

        $start = microtime(true);
        $query = $db->query($sql);

        $queries[] = microtime(true) - $start;
        return $query;
    }

    public function getCount() {
        return sizeof($this->queries);
    }

    public function getTime() { 
        return array_sum($this->queries);
    }

} // end QueryLogger class

$queryLogger = new QueryLogger;
```

Using this class, I can successfully query the database:

```
$results = $queryLogger->query("MY SQL QUERY HERE");
```

The problem is that I can not get it to return the total count or time of the queries using:

```
echo 'Ran '.$queryLogger->getCount().' queries in '.$queryLogger->getTime().' seconds.';
```

I always get 0 queries in 0 seconds. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot the object reference (`$this`).

```
$this->queries[] = microtime(true) - $start;
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great. Will accept when it lets me.

Comment: @JROB No problem. Happy coding!