# Having trouble adding values onto array from within PHP class

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is add a start & end timer to my sql queries so that I can track how many queries are being executed and how long it takes.

I use a PHP class I've written to handle all of my database connections and queries. It works fine. I just can't seem to write any values onto the `$queries` array, which would save the time elapsed for the query.

```
class db {

    public $queries = array(); // Can't write to this

    public function connect() {

        static $con;

        if (!isset($con)) { 
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','USER','PASS','DB');  
        }

        if ($con === false) {   
            mysqli_connect_error();     
        }

        return $con;

    } // end connect

    public function query($query) {

        $start = microtime(true); // Start here

        $con = $this->connect();

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        $queries[] = microtime(true) - $start; // Write to array

        return $result;

    }

    public function getCount() {
        return sizeof($this->queries);
    }

    public function getTime() {
        return number_format(array_sum($this->queries), 5);
    }

} // end db class

$db = new db;


$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($items = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Do some stuff
}

echo 'Ran '.$db->getCount().' queries in '.$db->getTime().' sec.'; // Always returns 0
```

I know I'm just missing something simple, I just can't seem to find what it is.

Comment: You're missing `$this` on `$queries[] = microtime(true) - $start;`  So `$queries` is locally scoped to that method -- should be `$this->queries`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You can post the exact same comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31994019/3933332 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$queries[]` with `$this->queries[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach object member you need to use `$this`:

```
$this->$queries[] = microtime(true) - $start; // Write to array
```

same, when you want to read from it, otherwise you are accessing `$queries` variable that is local to the method.

See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php